# VBA min value and table

Tags: vba

I have a sheet with 2 tables. I want to find and return the cell of column 1 which has the minimum proteges.
For example, my code would return either Phil,Levy or Sean, Montain in the first run. (then my spreadsheet will add +1 to one of the two - this is already set in excel). etc....

Coach List            Protégées 
Phil, Levy                7
Sean, Monteine            7
Victor, Chatelais         8

I have write a code but unfortunately ot does it randomly. Any thoughts ?

Code:

```
Dim Coach As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, t As ListObject, r As Long

    For Each t In MyWorksheet.ListObjects
        Select Case t.Name
            Case "Table1", "Table3", "Table4", "Table6", "Table8", "Table10", "Table12", "Table14", "Table16"
                'do nothing
            Case Else
                'Coach = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(t.ListColumns(2).Range)--> could use that ?
                For r = 1 To t.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
                For r = t.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
                    If t.DataBodyRange(r, 2) <= t.DataBodyRange(r + 1, 2) Then
                    Coach = t.DataBodyRange(r , 1)
                    End If
                Next r
        End Select
    Next t
```

Comment: Column 1 = Phil, Levy     Column 2 = 7 etc... For the table structure and values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Min Value and paste in at the end of a table VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971737/find-min-value-and-paste-in-at-the-end-of-a-table-vba)

Answer (score 0):

I think your method needs a variable for the lowest number found as each row is compared.

```
                p = 9999
                For r = 1 To t.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
                    If t.DataBodyRange(r, 2) <= p Then
                        p = t.DataBodyRange(r, 2)
                        Coach = t.DataBodyRange(r, 1)
                    End If
                Next r
```